# How can I send a public key generated with Elliptic Curve cryptography in a byte array, considering it's a class type?

Tags: python, class, cryptography, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I am using the cryptography python library to generate a key pair, using elliptic curve ([ECDHE](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#elliptic-curve-signature-algorithms)), to later perform a Diffie-Hellman key exchange with a device.

I noticed that the public_key I get is of type class, and more precisely, an EllipticCurvePublicKey class.

I cannot print it to the terminal, and when I do so, it obviously prints the address of it. But I need it to be sent through a buffer to a USB device, so how can I actually use it?

Copypasting the code below for reference:

The keys generation:

```
private_key = ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP256R1())
public_key = private_key.public_key()
```

The class and method in cryptography library:

```
@six.add_metaclass(abc.ABCMeta)
class EllipticCurvePrivateKey(object):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def signer(self, signature_algorithm):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def exchange(self, algorithm, peer_public_key):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def public_key(self):

    """
    The EllipticCurvePublicKey for this private key.
    """
```

Comment: To take a key object and convert it to bytes use [this](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.public_bytes). To go the other way, from bytes to a public key object, use the [serialization module](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/).

Comment: Thank you! I found out I needed to convert it to bytes as you said, and further decode it (from pem to der to public key).